# SonarQube Jenkins plugin invalid API call for key

Tags: sonarqube

The SonarQube Jenkins plugin makes an initial HTTP request for /api/server/version which responds 200 OK but then makes a request for /api/server/key which is not a valid action. The build then fails as the session is terminated with a 404 Not Found. Can anyone explain why an API request is made for key when it is invalid ? The plugin is version 2.3 and the server is version 5.2. Here is the actual response :

```
<error><code>404</code><msg>No action responded to key. Actions: admin_required, authorized?, available_locales, current_user, current_user=, error_to_json, error_to_xml, format_datetime, handle_remember_cookie!, has_role?, index, is_admin?, is_user?, java_facade, json_not_supported, jsonp, kill_remember_cookie!, load_resource, logged_in?, login_from_basic_auth, login_from_cookie, login_from_session, login_required, logout_keeping_session!, logout_killing_session!, parse_datetime, redirect_back_or_default, render_access_denied, render_bad_request, render_error, render_java_exception, render_not_found, render_response, render_success, resource_required, select_authorized, send_remember_cookie!, setup, store_location, text_not_supported, valid_remember_cookie?, version, and xml_not_supported</msg></error>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect those HTTP requests are made by the SonarQube scanner running as part of the build job, more than by the Jenkins plugin itself.

Check the [SonarQube scanner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARNEXT/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#InstallingandConfiguringSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AddingSonarQubeScanner) that you are using and make sure its version is compatible with SonarQube 5.2 (compatibility info can be found in the scanner documentation e.g [sonar-runner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner) , [Scanner for Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are using the latest version 2.3 of the following plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SonarQube+plugin - and it is configured as a Sonar post-build action. I do not see any compatibility issues with this.

Comment: Your plugin uses a SonarQube scanner under the hood, which you must have added in the Jenkins config for it to work (see [this documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#InstallingandConfiguringSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AddingSonarQubeScanner)). Which scanner version is used ? (if maven, which version of *sonar-maven-plugin*)

Comment: There is only one Sonar plugin which can be installed into Jenkins and this is named SonarQube. We are running version 2.3 as noted here http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins Do you know if this is compatible with Sonar 5.2 ?

Comment: From checking the console output of the job in Jenkins I can see the version of sonar-maven-plugin is 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that we were still using Maven 2.2.1 since upgrading to Sonar 5.2 whereas we needed to switch to Maven 3.x as noted here :

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven

Thanks to n_stan for the help on this.